# gdrive deleted matlab files in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, google-drive

I have installed the ubuntu gdrive software to synchronize my google drive files (originally creates in windows Machine).

When I start gdrive it requests me to login with my gmail account and downloads all the google drive folders (let me call folder X).

Then I update the files of X\Y folder in gdrive which works okey (Please note that X\Y folder was originally created in the windows google drive folder).

Unfortunately, yesterday afternoon, my gdrive asks me to enter my gmail account, and it re-synchronized the folder X\Y without the updated information.

Then when I check in google drive folder online activity icon, I have noticed that what I have done in the ubuntu machine is not uploaded in google drive folder cloud (Also when I contact google, they told me that they can not get my files since it does not exist in their cloud)?

The files are matlab codes (i.e., .m). I would appreciate to recover all the lost files in ubuntu machine. I know the date and the file names (less than 24 hours). I also used the "Restore missing files" default ubuntu software. But still not able to recover the files.

Please note that the files are deleted just by Gdrive (not accidental deletion). And I have a feeling that either gdrive or matlab softwares may have some ways to recover the deleted content.

Comment: What you call the "default Ubuntu software" is Déjà Dup, the backup program installed on Ubuntu. Are you implying you used Déjà Dup to back up the files?

Comment: When I right click the folder X\Y it says "Restore missing files" (I consider as the default recovery software). Thanks

Comment: Please note also that I have also tried "foremost" file carving software by updating foremost.conf as "m n 50000 function end ASCII". And using the command "foremost -v -T m -c /etc/foremost.conf -i /dev/sda -o /home/DestinationFolder/. I use "function" and "end" as the beginning and end of header since I look for matlab functions according to https://serverfault.com/questions/171026/foremost-custom-file-type-not-accepted-by-t-argument